# Can we thread the web-service and insert in in custom table cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

The thing is i have to make Custom cell of UITable, i have to call large webservice with many data which will take longer tym to load it once. So i want to apply threading in it. now my que is. can we at run -time insert value one by one in custom cell , as user will see data comming one by one at run time..?? if yes how we can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can ... try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{   
    myApp = (myAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startParsing) withObject:nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) startParsing
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startIndicator) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://abc.com"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    // 2 -- parsing
    parser = [[VolMyParser alloc] init];

    [parser parseXML:data];
    [data release];
    //[parser print];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    [pool release];
}

- (void) startIndicator
{
    av.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [av startAnimating];
}

- (void) updateTable
{
    [av stopAnimating];
    [myTable reloadData];

}
```

Hope its gives you an Idea...