# Use of activity indicator in xml parsing

Tags: iphone

I am new to IOS development. I am developing an app in which i have to do xml parsing. this is taking some time, so i want to display the Activity Indicator during this time. Could anyone let me know how to do it?
where to stast and stop the activity indicator;

Thanks for every help;

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510352/can-we-thread-the-web-service-and-insert-in-in-custom-table-cell/7510559#7510559

Comment: @Puneet Garg: You should respond to the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the little one in the top you use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES/NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start and stop in didReceiveResponse: and didFinishLoading: repectively

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Create the new view with activity indiactor(LoadingView)
Step 2:Call the showLoading method before you call the webservice
Step 3:Call removeLoading after completed the parsing xml

```
- (void)showLoading {   
    lview = [[LoadingView alloc] init];
    [self.view insertSubview:lview.view aboveSubview:self.parentViewController.view];
}
-(void)removeLoading{
      [lview.view removeFromSuperview];
     [lview release];
}
```